# Autocomplete textbox is not firing selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have an issue with my autocomplete textbox in my AngularJs app. When I press any key for autocomplete suggestion, my suggestion is shown in the textbox and the selected value is shown inside the textbox. When I try to show the value by its `ng-model` on the html page, it only shows the character I typed to get the autocomplete suggestion and not the suggested value.

Thank You!!!

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<input type="text" id="tags" data-ng-model="placeselected"  data-ng-keyup="complete()"/>
<br />{{placeselected}}
```

Here is my js:

```
$scope.complete = function() {
    $scope.availablePlaces = [];
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/orion-orbit/newclue/cities/ '+  $scope.cityselect.cityCode  + '/clueAnswers'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers,config) {
        $scope.getPlaces=data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers,config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
    angular .forEach($scope.getPlaces,function(value) {
        if (value.getPlaces !=' ') {
            $scope.availablePlaces.push(value.ans);
        }
    });


    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source : $scope.availablePlaces
    });
}
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$scope` to retrieve textbox's value, use `document.getElementById("id").value`

```
var pickup_location = document.getElementById("pickup_location").value;
```

Hope this helps!!