# Empty $scope element after jquery autocomplete on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mobile-safari, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm at a complete loss as to how to track down this error:
I built an autocomplete function into an input form within a modal dialog.
This works in Internet Explorer and Firefox. However, it causes problems on the iPhone and iPad (iOS 11.4.1 and Safari 11.1).

The autocomplete function works so far in Safari that I get suggestions. I can select and send them.
However, the Input Form does not transfer the entire proposal but only the first letters entered.

Example:

> "Te" (I entered) --> "Test" (I got from the autocompletion) --> "Te" (sent to the server)

What's going wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Test",
    "Test2",
    "Test2",
    "Test2",
    "Test234",
    "Testwer",
    "Testfgdfg",
    "Test234234",
    "Testsfsf",
    "Test3"
  ];
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});


jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Artikel" class="form-control autocomplete" autofocus/>
          <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
          </span>
        </div>




      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7jr31xp/10/).

Edit:
after all entries have been made, the function addTask is called, which creates a data record in the database.

```
$scope.addTask = function () {
    $http.post('script/create.php', {
        task: $scope.task
    })
        .then(function success(e) {

            $scope.errors = [];

            $scope.tasks.push(e.data.task);

            $scope.task = {
                name: ''
            }

            var modal_element = angular.element('#add_new_task_modal');
            modal_element.modal('hide');


        }, function error(e) {
            $scope.errors = e.data.errors;
        });

};
```

create.php

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

if (isset($data['task'])) {

    require __DIR__ . '/library.php';

    $name = (isset($data['task']['name']) ? $data['task']['name'] : NULL);
    $description = (isset($data['task']['description']) ? $data['task']['description'] : NULL);


   // Add the task
   $task = new Task();

   echo $task->Create($name, $description);

}
?>
```

Comment: how are you retrieving the `<input/>` value on submission to the server?

Comment: @AndrewLohr: Thanks for your reply. See above, I added the functions. is it possible that any changes or events are not triggered or differently triggered in Safari?

Comment: thanks, so in the `addTask` function the variable `$scope.task` is just "Te" like in your example you gave?

Comment: @AndrewLohr: correct! The "Te", the server receives.

Comment: on your input with `id="name"` I added the attribute `ng-model="task"` and then when you click save I called addTask() and it seems to print out the full word even when I click the autocomplete options that appears. If its still not working for you I think you'll need to create a complete and minimal working example that shows your problem.

Comment: The above comment was tested on Chrome, I forgot you mentioned it doesn't work on iphone and ipad - I don't have a readily available way to test that for you, sorry- this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042780/autocomplete-textbox-is-not-firing-selected-value

Comment: @AndrewLohr: thanks, no problem! but this is a very good clue. in my case I don't know how to replace the scope element with document.getElementById("name").value because I always pass on the scope element

Comment: sorry I do not know much angular so not sure what pass on the scope means, but did you try replacing `$scope.task` with `document.getElementById("name").value` ?